# Find match and copy data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following (sheet1):

```
State           Region
South Australia Aberfoyle Park
New South Wales Abermain
South Australia Adelaide
```

And then (sheet2):

```
State           Region          Long       Lat
Victoria        Abermain        -12.8167   51.4333
New South Wales Abermain        -32.8167   151.4333
South Australia Aberfoyle Park  -35.07     138.5885
```

I require an efficient way to search through `sheet1` and match the `Region` and `State` in `sheet2`, when a match is found I would like to create two new columns (in `sheet1`) that copies the matched `Long` and `Lat` from `sheet2`, the final output should look like (in `sheet1`):

```
State           Region          Long       Lat
South Australia Aberfoyle Park  -35.07     138.5885
New South Wales Abermain        -32.8167   151.4333
```

Note; sheet1 contains a lot of more data that is shown here so a simple copy past will not work :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, so far? You are more likely to get help when sharing your approach and asking for review. **Edit** to get started, research the MATCH function and experiment with the Macro Recorder in Excel.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/59482/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback nhee, my initial method used a combination of `IFS` and `MATCH`, unfortunately this got quite messey and I turned to the experts for guidance. In future I'll make sure to post my best efforts first. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sheet1!C2 you could gather the correct data from two-column-matching records in several ways. Here are three scenarios and examples.

1. Use a two-column criteria on a lookup based on the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a). There are *array* formulas that do this but I prefer standard formulas that do not require CSE. These only pick up the first occurrence of a matched pair of state/region but a minor rewrite can be made to return multiple matches into multiple rows. Example for C2:
    `=iferror(index(Sheet2!C$1:C$9999, min(index(row($1:$9999)+((Sheet2!$A$1:$A$9999<>$A2)+(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$9999<>$B2))*1e99, , ))), "")`
2. Use a simple [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5). This would work best when there are only one set of matching State/Region to return. Multiple matching pairs would produce incorrect, aggregated results. Example for C2:
    `=sumifs(Sheet2!C:C, Sheet2!$A:$A, $A2, Sheet2!$B:$B, $B2)`
3. If there are multiple matched pairs and you want a mean value returned from the average of the geographical points, use an [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-4CCA2550-DAB3-41C4-BCD2-648E17F20553). This would work best when there are multiple location points but will never return any one point unless there was only one set of matching State/Region to return. Example for C2:
    `=averageifs(Sheet2!C:C, Sheet2!$A:$A, $A2, Sheet2!$B:$B, $B2)`

After putting any of those examples into Sheet1!C2 for the latitude fill right one column to pick up the longitude and then fill C2:D2 down to pick up all of the matches.

Comment: Jeeped strikes again! thank you sir. Ended up using the `SUMIFS` function, worked as specified.